# why won't my large images in godaddy wont display?

Tags: html, css, cpanel, godaddy-api

So i have uploaded my website in godaddy and some of my 
[small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pySsz.png) images are displaying (sizes: 872 × 546px) but the large ones aren't displaying (the banners that has a size of 2700 × 900px). Does anyone know why this is happening?

This [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuFgg.png) shows when i check why my banner image wont load. Ive tried using  already but it still doesn't appear

edit: They are both located in the same folder

for the **large** images:

```
<section class="banner">
  <img src="img/WhyHim_Header.jpg" alt="whyhim" class="img-responsive">
</section>
```

for the **small** images:

```
<section class="polaroidimages">
    <img src="img/Image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please paste any relevant CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? Normally this kind of errors are related to either the path you have specified or the file name? Have you made sure the file name and extension are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check your file sizes -- per GoDaddy's documentation, images must be smaller than 30MB. Also, images larger than 1920 x 1080 may cause problems. If your filepaths are correct, this is likely the issue.

Comment: I have one of my images that's not appearing to be a size of 576x872 and it still wont appear. The other images that's showing are bigger than this and in the same folder but it still wont appear and i have no idea why

Comment: Godaddy have a help line, have you called?